# How to install the certificate used to sign an executable using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

This question is a follow up to [Programmatically getting an executable's Certificate Details](https://superuser.com/questions/1313410/programmatically-getting-an-executables-certificate-details).

I want to know how I can install the certificate to the cert store used to sign the executable using PowerShell.

I got the `SignerCertificate` details from the the executable using `Get-AuthenticodeSignature`. Now I need to know how I can install it to the cert store. `Export-Certificate` doesn't allow to export the certificate to a file.

Comment: You can only export a certificate after it's been installed to the certificate store.  I suspect this is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1506440/import-certificates-using-command-line-on-windows) question. You need the actual certificate file to do what you want though, so I suspect, you don't have the correct file.